# The dimension of $\operatorname{SL}(n,F)$ as a linear algebraic group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-groups

For an algebraically closed field $F$, what is the dimension of $\operatorname{SL}(n,F)$ as an algebraic group? Can anyone refer me to a place in the literature where this is calculated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dimension is $n^2-1$. It's a hypersurface in $F^{n^2}$ defined
by the equation determinant${}=1$. Any text on linear algebraic groups,
for instance that by Humphreys, will have this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know what the dimension of $Sp(2n,F)$ is?